# Removing Uppercase Letters from a String in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function eliminate that takes a string and 2 optional arguments. The first optional argument (bad_characters) takes a letter and the third argument (case_sensitive) takes a Boolean value. The function should take a string s and remove all instances of bad_characters. If case_sensitive is true, then the function should act case sensitive. If false, then it does not need to. This is what I have so far.

```
def eliminate(s,bad_characters = [],case_sensitive = True or False):
    ''' Takes a string s and returns the string with all bad_characters
    removed. If case_sensitive is True, then the function will only
    remove uppercase letters if there are uppercase letters in
    bad_characters.
    String --> String'''
    while True:
        if case_sensitive = False:
            for character in s:
                if bad_characters == character:
                    newlist = s.replace(bad_characters,'')
                    return newlist
        break
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make the function remove upper case letters if needed. The function should also work if bad_characters is a list, tuple, or string.

Comment: `True or False` == `True`. Is this your intention?

Comment: Why does `case_sensitive` remove only uppercase letters? this is odd. Perhaps name it `uppercase_only`?

Comment: Also, try in the python console the following: `'A' == 'a'`.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but never put an empty array `[]` as a default value in a python function or method. Instead use `bad_characters = None; ... if bad_characters is None: bad_characters=[]`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @DovGrobgeld you can do `bad_characters = bad_characters or []` since the arguments are not expected to be mutated anyway (so empty list passed in can be overrided by a different empty list).

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is miss understanding about `str.replace` because it just replace one character so you need to loop over `bad_characters` and remove them one by one.

SO instead of using `==` you can just use `in` operand,for check the membership, and then remove `character` from your string :

```
def eliminate(s,bad_characters = '',case_sensitive = False):
    ''' Takes a string s and returns the string with all bad_characters
        removed. If case_sensitive is True, then the function will only
        remove uppercase letters if there are uppercase letters in
        bad_characters.
        String --> String'''
    if case_sensitive == False:
        for character in s:
            if  character in bad_characters:
                s = s.replace(character,'')
        return s
```

And as a more pythonic way for remove a special characters from string you can use [*str.translate*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method :

```
s.translate(None,bad_characters)
```

Comment: The translate method is *the* Pythonic way to do this. +1 for mentioning it, while also addressing the OP's problem. Although I would've corrected the "True or False" parameter and improved the `bad_characters=''`, especially when we discuss the "Pythonic" way.

Comment: @OliverW. Pythonic way us not about the OP's solution any way thanks, for reminding fixed!;)

Comment: @Kasra IndentationError!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very handy `str.swapcase` function here. Please note that the below code overrides `bad_characters` for clarity, but you can easily modify it to keep it unchanged.

```
def eliminate(s, bad_characters, case_sensitive):    
    if not case_sensitive:
        bad_characters += map(str.swapcase, bad_characters)
    return ''.join([c for c in list(s) if c not in bad_characters])

print eliminate('AaBb', ['a'], False)    
print eliminate('AaBb', ['a'], True)    
print eliminate('AaBb', ['A'], True) 

Bb
ABb
aBb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = 'AbCdEfG'
print(''.join([x[0] for x in zip(a, a.upper()) if x[0] != x[1]]))
# bdf
```

Comment: This is not readable, probably hard to maintain if changes will be needed, and it doesn't relate to the argument pass in (`case_sensitive`).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `string.translate`(python2).

> string.translate(s, table[, deletechars])
>
> Delete all characters from s that are in deletechars (if present), and then translate the characters using table, which must be a 256-character string giving the translation for each character value, indexed by its ordinal. If table is None, then only the character deletion step is performed.

Other mistakes in the code:

- Initialize `case_sensitive` only with `True`. `True or False` is `True`.
- `While True` then `break` adds nothing. Remove it.
- `if case_sensitive = False:` is an assignment while you need a comparison `==`.  `case_sensitive` is a boolean, so just use it is `if case_sensitive` or `if not case_sensitive`.
- `bad_characters == character` is wrong. You cant compare a list to a character. use `character in bad_characters` instead.

Here is the whole solution with corrections:

```
def eliminate(s, bad_characters = [], case_sensitive = True):
    if case_sensitive: #True
        return s.translate(None, "".join(bad_characters))
    else: 
        s = s.translate(None, "".join(bad_characters).lower()) 
        s = s.translate(None, "".join(bad_characters).upper())
        return s
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def eliminate(s, bad_characters = [], case_sensitive=True):
    for character in bad_characters:
        if not case_sensitive:
            s = s.replace(character.lower(),'')
            s = s.replace(character.upper(),'')
        else:
            s = s.replace(character,'')
    return s
```